# Cable changing for Lapierre Audacio 400

Tags: road-bike, cable, cable-housing

Are there specific kinds of cables I should be going for? Specific tools that are must have to achieve this?

---

[This review](https://road.cc/content/review/142377-lapierre-audacio-400-road-bike)  shows the Audacio is a Shimano Tiagra groupset with rim brakes.

[image: From linked review]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brake a shifter cable and housings are fairly standardized, so you don't need a special type.

There is big difference between shifter and brake cables and housings. You absolutely must not use shifter cables/housings for brakes.

Brake cables have different ends for road and mountain bikes, so you need to make sure you get road brake cables.

Obviously you get to pick from different levels of quality from different manufacturers.

A cable cutter tool is needed to cut the cables and housings without squashing them. You do not want to use regular cutting pliers. I have found that a Dremel type tool with a metal cutting disc works well as it does not exert any force. It does melt the housing inner a bit though, so that needs to be cleaned out with a small drill bit.

If you have never changes cables and housings before then it's worth reviewing the proper procedures. Park Tool has great articles and videos. Here's a couple of links.

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/brake-housing-cable-installation-drop-bars

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cutting-and-sizing-cable-housing

If you have the existing cables and housings on the bike don't take them off and throw them away, use them to cut the new housings to the correct length.

Comment: It's always good to stick an awl into the housing and wiggle it around a bit after cutting it, to eliminate any burrs.

Comment: Forget simple steel cable (there are still some one sellers' shelves) use either stainless steel or better still (teflon) coated cables which you mustn't lubricate on insertion. And don't forget to buy suitable endcaps for the cables. They prevent fraying and nasty painful accidents.

Comment: There are "one bike kits" which come with enough outer, two inners, and a bag of ferrules and caps sufficient for one bike.  Wiggle certainly used to have them, saves buying a big box of the stuff.

Comment: I would also recommend a set. Several manufacturers offer sets, for example this one by Shimano which includes all parts for brake and shifter cables: https://www.bike-components.de/en/Shimano/Stainless-Steel-Road-Shifter-Brake-Cable-Set-p46854/

Comment: Thank you for the answers, this is of incredible help to me!